# RxJS timer doesn't wait for specified time?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to wrap my head around RxJS. While doing some testing, I ran into something that I can't figure out.

Here is the code :

```
let product = { id: 1, description: 'table' };

const asyncProduct = timer(2000).pipe(() => of(product));

asyncProduct.subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
```

I expected `product` to be logged into my console after 2 seconds, however, it logs right away for some reason. What do I misunderstand? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to emit after n seconds, you need to use `delay` operators not `timer`.

So you need to change your code in this way:

```
const asyncProduct = of(product).delay(2000)

asyncProduct.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

UPDATE:
You can use `timer` operator with `pipe` and then with another operator in it like the following:

```
timer(2000).pipe(
switchMap(() => of(product))
).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

In this way the value will emot after 2 seconds, achieving your goal. Is another way instead of the first example that I have provided before.

Comment: It seems like `timer` could be used as described in my example. I'm just not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: I have update the answer with a little explanation about timer operator. Check as correct if you think